# Python Selenium - how to click dynamic generated href page links

Tags: python, api, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver-python

I am automating a process using selenium with python. But I am stuck with something. I have to click a link using selenium. This link is href and it will be generated dynamically every time. The href link will be something like 3. For another page it will be 66

Now, to simulate the click of this link, is there any way to click it? How to get the dynamically generated link? I am using python code for selenium webdriver.

Sample tried "`self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "create_job_listing_ajax > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > center > a").click()`//copied URL as xpath

Comment: Share the URL if possible or HTML, code you have tried and the error.

Comment: please provide link to website.

Comment: Our API is under development and not launched yet. we are running selenium script on local environment. I will share the HTML code for reference,<center class="center_tag">  
<a style="color: #3064f5!important" id="xyz_match" href="/jobs/xyz_match/116/">1</a><br>xyz Match  </center>

Comment: Code tried:             self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@href,'xyz match')]").click() and error is "2021-09-07 10:38:06,089  Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@href,'xyz match')]"}
"

Comment: As per the CSS selector you are using, it looks like the `a` is within few `div` tags. Try to trace the `a` tag using that. Something like this `xpath` - `//div[...]//a`

Comment: Can you share bit more outer HTML, how does it look in UI ?

Comment: Sharing below the outer HTML code for reference, @cruisepandey  '**<div class="col" style="padding:2px 5px"><center class="center_tag">   
  
          <a style="color: #3064f5!important" href="/jobs/xyz_match/117/">4</a>

     <br>xyz Match  </center></div>**'

Answer (score 1):

Since we do not have `enough HTML` to proper give the `working xpath` or any other `locater`, the best way is to use the `below xpath.`

```
//div[@class='col']/center[@class='center_tag']/a
```

See in the end we are able to reach to `a tag` which has a attribute `href` that is getting generated dynamically.

Now you should always check in HTML DOM.

Steps to check :

```
Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> do a CTRL  + F -> then paste  and see `//div[@class='col']/center[@class='center_tag']/a` is getting highlighted or not.
```

also we have to make sure that we do not get multiple nodes using that xpath. check extreme right how many entry do we have ? It should be `1/1` to make this to work.

**Code :**

```
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='col']/center[@class='center_tag']/a").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

you wrote very gifficult, make it easer!

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#create_job_listing_ajax > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > center > a'))).click()
```

or

```
self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#create_job_listing_ajax > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > center > a').click()
```

Comment: Hi Vadim, I have tried the above code and showing the following error **'TestLoginpage' object has no attribute 'browser'**

Comment: try it https://wiki.mozilla.org/Converting_IDE_scripts_to_Python

Comment: do it copy 'selector' do not do copy xpath

Comment: if you do copy xpath use it https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#:~:text=driver.find_element(By.XPATH%2C